# SmartGWT: How can i add a record inside a specific Node of my Tree

Tags: smartgwt

I have a tree inside a TreeGrid, the tree has different nodes.

What I want is to add the selected Record (I have the record with me) inside a specific node (i.e favorite node).

What I can achieve is only to add the record inside a TreeGrid, but it should insert inside a specific node (let's say the first Node in my treeGrid).

How can I achieve this?

code snippet:

```
private AnimateTreeNode favoriteNode = new AnimateTreeNode("My Favorites");

    TreeGrid clientTreeGrid = new TreeGrid(); 
    Tree clientTree = new Tree(); 

    clientTree.setModelType(TreeModelType.CHILDREN);  
    clientTree.setNameProperty("My space");  
    clientTree.setRoot(new AnimateTreeNode("fav",favoriteNode);

    clientTreeGrid.setData(clientTree);  
    clientTreeGrid.setCanReparentNodes(false);  
    clientTreeGrid.setSelectionType(SelectionStyle.SINGLE);

    favoritesMenuItem.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {  
    public void onClick(MenuItemClickEvent event) {  
        UserRecord record = (UserRecord) userGrid.getSelectedRecord();
        categoryTree.addData(record);        
    }  
});
```

Comment: Can you try add(TreeNode node, TreeNode rootNode) method of Tree. This will add record under specified root node.

Comment: in your above method , where i am mentioning that record which i want to insert , its only telling the location, Actually i am trying to save a Record inside a tree , but its just addind a Node , please suggest

Answer (score 1):

UserRecord seems to be a record from other component i.e. UserGrid. So what you can do here is, form a node out of information from the selected record and add it to a Tree. Let me know if it works for you.

**EDIT:** Following code snippet may help you further.

```
TreeGrid sampleTreeGrid = new TreeGrid();
    sampleTreeGrid.setShowHeader(false);
    TreeGridField sampleTreeGridField = new TreeGridField("testMenu", " ");

    TreeNode rootNavNode = new TreeNode("root");
    rootNavNode.setAttribute("testMenu", "root");

    TreeNode testNode = new TreeNode();
    testNode.setTitle("Test Node");
    testNode.setAttribute("testMenu", "Test Node");



    Tree mainTree = new Tree();
    mainTree.setRoot(rootNavNode);

    mainTree.setModelType(TreeModelType.PARENT);
    mainTree.setNameProperty("mainTreeTitle");
    mainTree.add(testNode, mainTree.getRoot());

    sampleTreeGrid.setData(mainTree);
    sampleTreeGrid.setFields(sampleTreeGridField);
```

Key part here is assigning created node. Don't add record directly to a TreeGrid. You should create a new tree node from selected record from user grid and then add that node to the location you wish to.

Comment: can you guide please ,How to assign record to a Node, here is what i am doing    :  UserRecord record = (UserRecord) userGrid.getSelectedRecord();
    categoryTreeGrid.addData(record);
TreeNode node = new TreeNode("new");
node

Comment: you are not creating a new tree node from selected record from user grid in the above code , I am not able to assign a Record to the node ,plz if you can show me how to put a record inside a tree node

Comment: In TreeGrid you use TreeNode to add them dynamically based on respective information that you get from else where. Here in your get case, you have that information from selected record of user grid. The concept here is on select event of user grid record you create a new node instead of adding record and add it under the node you wish. I hope this clears out your doubt about how to dynamically add node to the location you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read your selected record and set the different attibutes of a new node with the value of the fields of your record you are interested in. After that you add the new node to the `Tree` and set the data of your treegrid to your `Tree`.  A node get a Title,  Name Id and your attributes if you want to add some. A `ListGridRecord` don't have these attributes. I don't think there is an automatic way of doing this.